# Using custom Environment Variables in JetBrains products for File watcher Arguments

Tags: environment-variables, phpstorm, webstorm

I am trying to use [`node-sass`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) as File Watcher in WebStorm.

I created a local variable named `STYLE` with main stylesheet name inside to add it as variable to File Watcher settings everywhere it needed.

But if I add `$STYLE$` in a Path I get an error:

```
/Users/grawl/Sites/sitename/node_modules/node-sass/bin/node-sass app/styles/$STYLE$.scss public/$STYLE$.css
error reading file "app/styles/$STYLE$.scss"


Process finished with exit code 1
```

IDE just don't interprets my variable.

*Also I tried to use `%STYLE%` but with no luck.*

*Please do not blame me for direct mapping filenames in File Watcher without using built-in variables like `$FileName$` or `$FileNameWithoutExtension$` because even WebStorm 9 EAP does not support preprocessor's dependencies except of built-in preprocessors like Sass and Jade.*

[image]

#### This case is not only case to use local variables.

For example I want to put into variables my `public/` path (that can be `dest/` in other projects) and `app/` (can be `source/`). And so on.

**So let's figure out this feature.**

Comment: AFAIK you cannot reference environment variables inside IDE. In any case: instead of calling SASS compiler directly, make a shell script that will do such compilation for you and call this script instead.

Comment: @LazyOne thank you! This is a great idea. I will try it on a week.